# Calculate the product $A^{10}v$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $v$ is a vector $[4 \; 4]^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Following on from the title, can someone suggest how to proceed with this one.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\4&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$v = [4 \; 4]^T?$$

Comment: One way could be to multiply $A$ by itself nine times then by $v$ from the right. It is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- calculate $Av$, and then apply $A$ to the result nine times;
- or, since the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, $A$ is diagonalizable: there exist $P$ invertible and $D$ diagonal with $A=PDP^{-1}$. Then $A^{10}=PD^{10}P^{-1}$, where $D^{10}$ is very easy since it's diagonal.

Comment: I disagree with the first one. I'd rather calculate $A^{10}$ and then apply it to $v$. :P

Comment: That sounds very inefficient. Each time you multiply two $2\times 2$ matrices you are doing 8 products and four sums; so to calculate $A^{10}$ you are doing $9\times 8+2=74$ products and $9\times 4+1=37$ sums, whereas if you apply $A$ to $v$ and keep doing it, each time you are doing 2 products and one sum, for a total of $10\times 2=20$ products and $10\times 1=10$ sums.

Comment: Haha. Yes. This proves that I should never design algorithms. But still, both methods are too inefficient for calculation by hand. That's what I meant. :P (+1) for both the comment and the answer.

Comment: In general, yes. But at this stage, with the 10th power, when you compare with finding the two eigenvalues, two corresponding eigenvectors, then inverting the matrix with the eigenvectors and columns, and then doing the two products in $PD^{10}P^{-1}$, "brute force" is probably less or similar work. It won't as soon as you increase powers.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, when I apply $A$ to $v$, I count *four* products and *two* sums, not two products and one sum. Am I miscounting?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Contrary to what @stressedout seems to think, algorithms are not my thing :D

Comment: My argument still survives, though.

Comment: Consider a possibility to calculate $A^2$ then $A^4$ then $A^8$ then $A^{10}$, in total, 4 matrix multiplications.

Comment: If you compute $A^2$ and then $A^4=(A^2)^2$, you can then compute $A^2v$ followed by $A^4(A^2v)$ followed by $A^4(A^4(A^2v))$, with a total of $8+8+4+4+4=28$ multiplications and $4+4+4+2+2=14$ additions.

Comment: I love how everyone is calculating the number of additions and multiplications necessary to solve this like it is actually an important problem. :P @Martin I never thought algorithms were your thing. But I said that I should never design them. :D

Comment: @stressedout, the explicit question posed here may not be all that important, but the underlying question of how to efficiently organize a matrix calculation certainly is.  Incidentally, I could see closing the question here as a PSQ, but I don't see it as a duplicate.  Calculating $A^{1000}$ is almost certainly best done by diagonalizing the matrix, but $A^{10}$ is a small enough power that other options are worth considering.

Comment: @BarryCipra The OP simply asked how to do it, not about the most computationally efficient method of doing so. That’s covered and then some in the duplicate question. Organizing matrix calculations efficiently is certainly of practical importance, but without more context in the question, it seems a bit off-topic here.

Comment: @amd, I think we're basically on the same page here, except that I didn't see anyone at the ostensible duplicate mention the possibility of repeatedly squaring the matrix (which makes sense, since it would hardly make sense to approach the calculation that way for such a large power).

Comment: @BarryCipra It’s not an entirely unreasonable approach even for a large power—for 1000 it reduces the number of matrix multiplications to 10 or so.

Comment: I miscounted. It’s actually many fewer than ten.